# MySQL distinct or group by in combination with having not giving a result when result is a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

It seems that my query is not exactly doing what I want. The query gets a result aslong as the result is 2 or more rows. When I get a single row the query is not getting any result.

In the `SELECT` I can do `DISTINCT (ct.name)` but this gives the same problem as the group by.

```
SELECT  
   ct.name, 
   ( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(52.779716)) * cos(radians( com.gps_lat )) * cos(radians( com.gps_lon ) -
   radians(21.84803)) + sin( radians(52.779716) ) * sin( radians( com.gps_lat )))) as distance 
FROM cuisine_types as ct
```

Left joining company to check if a company is attached to the cuisine_type

```
LEFT JOIN company AS com ON (com.cuisine_type_id = ct.id)
```

Here I'm grouping the results so no Cuisine Type appears twice.
this only seems to work when the result is 2 or more rows...

```
GROUP BY ct.name
```

Here I'm checking if the distance of the company is within the users preferenced search radius

```
HAVING distance < 20;
```

for example if I had 'Fastfood', 'Vegan', and 'Healthy' as Cuisine Types, I only want one of each Cuisine Types no matter how many companies in the search distance are related to that Cuisine Type. So I filter the double Cuisine Types away using the GROUP BY I hope this helps with understanding my approach in this query.

NOTE: There is only one Cuisine Type attached to a company.

Full sql query without comments down here

> SELECT ct.name, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.779716) ) * cos(
>   radians( com.gps_lat ) ) * cos( radians( com.gps_lon ) -
>   radians(21.84803) ) + sin( radians(52.779716) ) * sin( radians(
>   com.gps_lat ) ) ) ) as distance FROM cuisine_types as ct LEFT JOIN
>   company AS com ON (com.cuisine_type_id = ct.id) GROUP BY ct.name
>   HAVING distance < 20;

Comment: it doesnt give result at all or wrong result?

Comment: When the result is 1 row there is no result visible (I know there should be one)

Comment: If you get rid of the Group By and Having, does your single row appear?

Comment: IF I remove the GROUP BY the one result appears, when I remove the HAVING too, all the rows in the cuisine_type table appear + company table fields (if available).

Comment: What is the value of distance for the single row?

Comment: exactly 17.4713944772963

Comment: If there are multiple rows for each cuisine type, how do you know which row's distance is being selected? Try putting a min() around your distance calculation.  That will give you the closest location.

Comment: That in fact doesn't matter, if for example I had 'Fastfood', 'Vegan', and 'Healthy' as Cuisine Types, I only want one of each Cuisine Types no matter how many companies in the search distance are related to that Cuisine Type. So I filter the double Cuisine Types away using the GROUP BY I hope this helps with understanding my approach in this query. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   ct.name, 
   min( ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.779716) ) * cos( radians( com.gps_lat ) ) * cos( radians( com.gps_lon ) - radians(21.84803) ) + sin( radians(52.779716) ) * sin( radians( com.gps_lat ) ) ) ) ) as distance 
FROM
   cuisine_types as ct 
      LEFT JOIN company AS com ON (com.cuisine_type_id = ct.id) 
GROUP BY 
   ct.name 
HAVING 
   distance < 20;
```

Comment: The addition of the `MIN` aggregate function (around the distance expression) makes the query deterministic. Absent that `MIN` function (as in the OP query), MySQL is free to choose whichever one row it wants from `com`, and if that one row happens to result in a `distance` result greater than 20, then MySQL will not return a row.

Comment: This is true, but when only one row is checked in the `HAVING` and the `distance` is smaller than 20 MySQL also not returns it.

Comment: @ChrisSmits Using MIN works in my testing. Can you post some sample data?